# How to change the Slug Link of an Attribute (pa_) in WooCommerce?

Tags: woocommerce, hyperlink, attributes, slug

If u add informations in WooCommerce you get the "Additional Informations". I need to use them as a taxonomy to Filter my products. If i use them as a taxonomy they change to a "Link" (Permalink). The Link always starts with "pa_" but that doesn't filter the products. All products are always Shown. So i need to change the value of the Link to an working permalink:

?pa_Test=Hallo
?swoof=1&post_type=product&pa_test=Hallo

I hope anyone can help me, because everyone who is using WooCommerce should have the same Problem...

I tried to find the right coding area, but never found a way to change the value "pa". I tried diffrent Filter Plugins but this don't change the Value (because it is basic WooCommerce". I also Treid to turn the taxonomy off (so noone needs to click on the link" but the i can't filter for the taxonomies.

Comment: Tahnk you for your help, but that was obvious. I could solve the problem. I had to create a new Shop Page. So i Added one over Templates - Theme Builder Product Archives. Then i added a Product Archive and the Side-Bar with my Filters. I set the condition All Product Archives, Shop Page, Product Category, Product Tags and after thet it worked.